# Can not understand load returned by sysinfo

Tags: c, sysinfo

To find the load average in linux I use sys/sysinfo.h which include linux/kernel.h, where the following structure is defined:

```
struct sysinfo {
long uptime;            /* Seconds since boot */
unsigned long loads[3];     /* 1, 5, and 15 minute load averages */
unsigned long totalram;     /* Total usable main memory size */
unsigned long freeram;      /* Available memory size */
unsigned long sharedram;    /* Amount of shared memory */
unsigned long bufferram;    /* Memory used by buffers */
unsigned long totalswap;    /* Total swap space size */
unsigned long freeswap;     /* swap space still available */
unsigned short procs;       /* Number of current processes */
unsigned short pad;     /* explicit padding for m68k */
unsigned long totalhigh;    /* Total high memory size */
unsigned long freehigh;     /* Available high memory size */
unsigned int mem_unit;      /* Memory unit size in bytes */
char _f[20-2*sizeof(long)-sizeof(int)]; /* Padding: libc5 uses this.. */
};
```

but I think it doesn't give true load.

output :
   2552402, 3214049236, 134513148

What does this value mean?

We can find current load using the `uptime` command:

```
$uptime
13:00:14 up 35 min,  2 users,  load average: 1.07, 0.95, 0.80
```

I can't find any connection between above the two outputs.

---

I have searched on internet. [This](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/load-average-return-values-from-sysinfo-309720/) says that divide it by 2^16 (65536). and I have tried it too. 
(or do shift 1 by SI_LOAD_SHIFT  i.e.   1 << SI_LOAD_SHIFT. because 65536 = 1 << 16)

I use computer which has four i3-2120 processor. Output of 'upitime' has connection with number of cpus. [Wikipedia load_average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29)

Comment: What kernel are you running? What results do you get after divion by `1 << SI_LOAD_SHIFT`? It works fine on my box (3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP x86_64)

Comment: possible duplicate of [sysinfo system call returns wrong load average values on linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993158/sysinfo-system-call-returns-wrong-load-average-values-on-linux)

Comment: Kernel version is   Linux 3.0.0-21-generic #35~lucid1-Ubuntu SMP.  
If i divide load by (1 << SI_LOAD_SHIFT), I get output as 
113, 49088, 2052.

Comment: You can view my code at http://codepad.org/FuxWFd0P

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the link you gave, you should scale the loads according to the `SI_LOAD_SHIFT` constant (included by `sys/sysinfo.h`), and introduce the number of available CPUs to convert it into CPU usage %:

```
struct sysinfo sysinf;
memset(&sysinf, 0, sizeof sysinf);
if (!sysinfo(&sysinf)) {
    float f_load = 1.f / (1 << SI_LOAD_SHIFT);
    printf("load average (1 min): %.2f (%.0f%% CPU)\n",
        sysinf.loads[0] * f_load,
        sysinf.loads[0] * f_load * 100/get_nprocs());
    // process other loads as well of you need
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The load averages are represented in fixed point arithmetic. See [here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.5.3/include/linux/sched.h#L111) for the relevant constants. We see that the last FSHIFT bits are used to represent the fractional part. To get the load averages, you can always do it like [/proc/loadavg](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.5.3/fs/proc/loadavg.c).

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

I forgot to call `sysinfo(&sysinfo_obj)` function.