# how to interprete sinfo cpu load %O?

Tags: cpu, hpc, slurm, uptime

`sinfo --format "%O"` gives the load of nodes.

Is this an average value of a specific time period?

And how is this value related with the load averages (`1m,5m,15m`) of `uptime` command?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it returns the 5min load average value.

`SLURM` uses [sysinfo](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysinfo.2.html) to measure the cpu load value (am using `slurm 15.08.5`).

In the source code of slurm, the following line measures the cpu load value.

```
float shift_float = (float) (1 << SI_LOAD_SHIFT);
if (sysinfo(&info) < 0) {
    *cpu_load = 0;
    return errno;
}
*cpu_load = (info.loads[1] / shift_float) * 100.0;
```

From the `sysinfo` man page:

```
           unsigned long loads[3];  /* 1, 5, and 15 minute load averages */
```

`info.loads[1]` returns the 5min average. `sysinfo` reads from the file `/proc/loadavg`

To understand why `SI_LOAD_SHIFT` is used, please read the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303141/can-not-understand-load-returned-by-sysinfo/12303849#12303849)